# Where did $-3$ go in this algebra problem?

Tags: linear-algebra

Where did the $-3$ go whilst trying to get the value of $x$? It just disappeared for some reason.

> To find the $x$-value that corresponds to $\color{red}y=\color{red}{-2}$, let's substitute this $y$-value in the equation:
>
> $$\begin{align}
> \color{red}y+2&=-3(x-4)\\
> \color{red}{-2}+2&=-3(x-4)\\
> 0&=-3(x-4)\\
> 0&=x-4\\
> 4&=x
> \end{align}$$

Comment: if $ab=0$ then either $a=0$ or $b=0$, or both. But here, we have $a=-3$ and $b=(x-4)$, and obviously $-3\neq0$ so it follows that $(x-4)=0$.

Comment: this is just algebra, not linear algebra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was divided to the left hand side and $0/(-3)=0$ so it's just ... gone.

Comment: if it did happen then why was (x-4) unaffected?

Comment: Because that part was *not* divided to the left hand side.  In general if $a=bc$ then $a/b=c$ (as long as $b\not=0)$.  In your case $a=0$, $b=-3$ and $c=x-4$

Answer (score 1):

Operations involving $0$ behave differently to normal operations. $0$ acts as a [annihilator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilator_%28ring_theory%29) - information in does not come back out again.

The process is similar to light in a [black hole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole).

So, as according to [group theory](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Group.html), $0x=0$.

You actually perform two operations with $0$ in your question (although not necessarily in this order):

1. $0.-1=0$
2. $0/3=0$

So you could say the $-3$ disappears into a black hole. Where does it re-appear? We don't know!

Alternatively, we could say 'the $-3$ vanished into thin air'.